# CSV file, change cell value

Tags: powershell

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjGvZ.png

```
productNumber                 productName       active description
-------------                 -----------       ------ -----------
productNumber                 productName       active description
1A100110001                   product1          TRUE   laptop
1A100110002                   product2          TRUE   laptop
1A100110003                   product3          TRUE   laptop
1A100110004                   product4          TRUE   laptop
1A100110005                   product5          TRUE   laptop
1A100110006                   product6          TRUE   laptop
1A100110007                   product7          TRUE   laptop
1A100110008                   product8          TRUE   laptop
1A100110009,product9,FALSE,PC
```

I would like to change the value of the productName (product2) to (product fortnox 2)

I tried the following code but it didin't work:

```
$products_fortnox = import-csv -Path .\products_Fortnox_output.csv 
$products_fortnox | % {

if ($_.productNumber -eq "1A100110002") {

$_.productName = 'product fortnox 2'
} 
}

$products_fortnox | export-csv .\products_Fortnox_output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: the code looks good...the issue is with ur csv file...it looks like there are 2 header rows...also the csv may not be a well-formed

Comment: so you mean that the problem with the csv file?

Comment: Check your CSV. Looks like the line for `product9` uses commas as delimiter where the other lines use something else. Product9 ends up as a single value for the `productNumber` column now.

Comment: Please don't post picture representation of your data (also in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178569/add-new-line-to-the-end-of-csv-with-powershell)) either post the real csv file or the Object after Importing as **text**. Once you `Export-Csv` the values are all duoble quoted, what may explain the last Row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$source  = '.\products_Fortnox_output.csv '
$dest   = '.\products_Fortnox_output_new.csv '

[IO.File]::ReadAllText($filepath) -replace '(?m)^(1A100110002,)(prod.*)(,.*)$', '$1product fortnox 2$3' | Out-File $dest
```